# Check if a point in rectangle

Tags: math, geometry

I have:

1. axis-aligned rectangle *R*;
2. non-vertical line *A* (specified by two points);
3. vertical line *B* (specified by x-coordinate).

All objects above is specified by **integer coordinates**.

I need to **check, if result of crossing *A* and *B* is in the *R*.** But I can't just calculate result of crossing *A* and *B* because it may be unpresentable in integer coordinates. Also I can't convert it to doubles because I need to get absolutely accurate result without any inaccuracy.

So, how can I check it?

Comment: why do you think using `double` will be _less_ accurate than using integers?

Comment: The y coordinate of the crossing is a rational number, so what you want can be done. Note that you only need to check the y coordinate, since whether B intersects R or not is sufficient for checking the x one. The potential problem is integer overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If lines are specified by integer coordinates, then their crossing point has rational coordinates, which may be compared with absolutely precision.

Let's A goes through points (ax0, ay0) and (ax1, ay1), and B is at X0 coordinate.
Then crossing point Y-coordinate is (ay0*(ax1-ax0)+(X0-ax0)*(ay1-ay0))/(ax1-ax0) = p/q, where p and q are integer, and q is positive (negate nominator if needed).

Then p may be compared with R.Top*q and R.Bottom*q

Answer (score 0):

[let's ignore not interesting case when B does not intersect R]

R cuts a segment from B, let's call it S. Intersection of B and A lies inside of R if and only if A crosses S.

Finding points of S is trivial.

To check whether a line crosses a segment, you should check that ends of S lie on different sides from A - this can be checked by signed angles.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the 2 points on A are `(x0, y0)` and `(x1, y1)`, with 'x0 < x1'.

The rectangle is determined by a x-coordinate `xR` and a y-coordinate `yR`

The B line is determined by the x-coordinate `xB`

The point you're looking for is `(xB, yB)`, where `yB` is to be determined somehow, by manipulating integers only :

So first, you need to check

1. if `xB * xR >= 0` (same side of the x-coordinate)
2. if `abs(xB) <= abs(xR)` (the B line cuts the rectangle)

If it's ok, then you need to check that this integer (which is equal to (x1-x0)yB)

```
Y = (y1-y0)(xB-x0)+(x1-x0)y0
```

verifies

1. `Y * yR >=0` (same side of the y-coord)
2. `abs(Y) <= (x1-x0) * abs(yR)` (meaning that your intersection point is in the R area regarding its y-coord)

Your point is inside R if and only if the 4 conditions are true.
Hope it helps.